# How am i supposed to restrict the user to remove the last element from the multiselect

Tags: jquery-select2

I want to lock the last element from the multiselect to be removed. Ideally, there is always a default value and user cannot remove all the values from the multiselect. He/she has to keep atleast one in the multiselect. How can i get this done?

Comment: Do a on change event to count how many elements are left. If the count is 1, display an error and return false. Edit: You should post what you have so far on jsfiddle so everyone can see your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
  .on("select2-removing", function (event) {
    if ($(this).val().length === 1) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  })
```